# Unable to implement login with facebook because facebook is giving an error using angular8?

Tags: angular, typescript, facebook-login

I have an `angular8` application in which i have to implement login with `facebook`. I am using `angularx-social-login`. But when i tried to login facebook popup opens with warning like this

[image]

And after login this popups is coming and i am getting `user` object `null`

[image]

In `facebook developers console` i put these settings

[image]

In `settings` in `facebook developers console` i added `platform` as `web` and enter this setting

[image]

I have implemented in `stackBlitz` here is my code at this  [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tnzly4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a valid redirect url in Client OAuth Settings.

[image]
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ad1hb8

Comment: ahh right. So where i can find `Client OAuth Settings` in facebook developers console

Comment: You put `https://localhost:4200/` in `Client OAuth Settings`settings but on my local machine i have `http` instead of `https`. And when i am entering this `http://localhost:4200/` so it's giving an error on this field. It is only accepting url with `https`. So what can i do now?

Comment: i figured out. I didn't put any url in `Client OAuth Settings` and just put `App Domain` as `localhost` and `Site Url` as `http://localhost:4200/` so it's working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: For stackblitz you will be able to add http and for localhost - http redirects are automatically allowed while in development mode only and do not need to be added here.

Answer (score 0):

Use virtual host instead for your project.

Create self signed certificate and use `https` url. You don't really need this step but I prefer enforcing `HTTPS`.

Here is an [article](https://wp-native-articles.com/blog/news/how-to-fix-facebook-apps-error-cant-load-url-domain-url-isnt-included-apps-domains/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have read this article but i didn't what to do with settings to run fb app using my angular app on `localhost`

Comment: Have you tried virtual host? Virtual host works for my projects.